# Hacking into an electric hoist using SSR's and an arduino. Why is this happening?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, resistors, solid-state-relay

So I've been working on hacking into an electric hoist so I am able to control its movements using my Arduino. My idea was to wire into the remote control that comes with the hoist. The remote control joins to pairs of wires when you press up, and two other pairs of wires when you press down, so I wanted to recreate that function but with solid state relays that are controlled by an Arduino. To test this, I added the SSRs and 2 buttons to simulate the remote control. When I did this, the hoist only seemed to work the first time I pressed one of the buttons, and then stopped working after. After some troubleshooting, I found that one side of the control had a resistance, but the other didn't. So I decided to add resistors across the other side, this worked! It now works well. My question is, why? Why does it not need resistors there when using the manual controls, but it does when using the SSRs? I have attached a bunch of photos to show everything I have done, along with all the internal wiring in the hoist. If I can provide any more information, let me know!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What’s the voltage across the button/switch when not pressed? What’s the load downstream of it (unplug the unit, set your DMM to Ohm and measure the resistance)? Impossible to tell without more information, but it’s certainly possible the inputs to the actual circuit in the motor controller is high ohmic and way above the hold current of your SSRs.

Comment: Great and detailed photos, can you add a schematic?

Comment: what does the front of the control look like? ... it is unclear where the up and down buttons are

Comment: I imagine most EE pros regard the term "hacking" as derogatory.

Comment: those SSRs are clearly labeled as designed (triac) for AC power, but you're switching DC power; they won't work. Use DC SSRs, or their actual equivalent: mosfets. Or mechanical relays if you want to be weak. btw, an hbridge module would do all that for you..